# VS Code keeps changing my "editor.formatOnPaste" setting to true

Tags: visual-studio-code

The setting `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` keeps magically reappearing in my VS Code user settings. What is causing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question. It was happening whenever I clicked the [Formatting Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tombonnike.vscode-status-bar-format-toggle) status bar button. By default it toggles both `editor.formatOnSave` 
 **and** `editor.formatOnPaste` whenever you click it.

Added this to my user settings to fix it:

```
"formattingToggle.activateFor": [
    "formatOnSave"
]
```

Comment: Now is `"formattingToggle.affects": ["editor.formatOnSave"]`